# Count of rows with same field value

Tags: mysql

I have query

```
SELECT
    salesorderid,
    integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id,
    vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
INNER JOIN vtiger_products ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
INNER JOIN integration_betapost.goods_to_products ON vtiger_products.productid = integration_betapost.goods_to_products.productid
WHERE
    sostatus = 'Отправлять'
```

Which is returning this [result](http://joxi.ru/823KeVztNQaL2O).

How could I get count of rows with the same `salesorderid` and count of rows with same `salesorderid` and `shipping_order_row_good_id`?

Comment: search `GROUPBY` & `AGGREGATE` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause in your query

```
SELECT
    salesorderid,
    integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id,
    COUNT(Quantity)
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
INNER JOIN vtiger_products ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
INNER JOIN integration_betapost.goods_to_products ON vtiger_products.productid = integration_betapost.goods_to_products.productid
WHERE
    sostatus = 'Отправлять'
GROUP BY
    salesorderid
    ,integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id
```

If you want to sum the quantity of each `salesorder` and `integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id`, you can change `COUNT` for `SUM`.